# telethon JoinChatlistInviteRequest exeption "The include_peers vector of the filter is empty"

Tags: python, telethon

my code is:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

api_id = '****'
api_hash = '****'

phone_number = '+****'

with TelegramClient(phone_number, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    try:
        user = client.get_entity('@****')

        # Use types module for InputPeerUser
        user1 = types.InputPeerUser(user_id=user.id, access_hash=user.access_hash)
        print(user1)
        # Ensure that peers is a non-empty list
        result = client(functions.chatlists.JoinChatlistInviteRequest(
            slug='https://t.me/addlist/****',
            peers=[user1]  # Make sure the list is not empty
        ))
        print(result.stringify())
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
```

and my output is:

```
InputPeerUser(user_id=****, access_hash=-****)
Error: The include_peers vector of the filter is empty (caused by JoinChatlistInviteRequest)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So userPeer is not empty, it exists, if smth was wrong with it initialization, I would get exeption on types.InputPeerUser() step , am I wrong?
So if peer exists, how do i get "The include_peers vector of the filter is empty"?

I expect it to work(

Comment: While I've been writing this question somehow it started to work, I don't get that exception, but now I get "INVITE_SLUG_EXPIRED" exception... (link for a slug was created like 5 min ago)

Comment: The "slug" often refers to a friendlier name as explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Slug. You may not need to pass the entire URL. Only the final part.